# Difference between 'He is on the move' and 'He is moving'?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between 'He is on the move' and 'He is moving'?

Comment: "He is moving" can mean many things based on the context, but one can say "he is on the move" to inform others that someone is moving from point A to the point B.
Also see here: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on-the-move

Answer (score 1):

**moving** is abstract.  Not remaining perfectly still or not remaining at one location. It can also mean "relocating to a new address".

**He is on the move** is an informal phrase that means "he has left the place where he has been for some time, and he is now, even as we speak, on his way to another location".

A police or espionage surveillance team might say of a suspect they have been secretly watching:

**The suspect is on the move.**

The phrase can also have the figurative meaning of "making progress in some endeavor or enterprise".

**The new startup company is on the move.**